# Determining Which Function was returned when your code returns multiple functions based on input

Tags: node.js, functional-programming

i have a function that takes an input, and returns one of two functions based on the input. any idea how to assert which function was returned?  (In this case NodeJS)

Comment: Call it and check what it does. You shouldn't assert anything else about functions.

Comment: why would you want to know that? you can always use (fn).name to get the functions name. but that wouldn't work if the function is anonymous. can you share a bit more about your use case?

Comment: If the functions are static (not closures), you could make them globals so that you can assert their identity.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas.

```
function a (foo) {};
function b (foo, bar) {};

function c (one, two) { return one };

const functionResult = c(a, b);

console.log(functionResult.name === 'a'); // if functions are not function expresions you can assert using name
console.log(functionResult.length === 1); // assert using known arity
console.log(functionResult === a); // assert with standard equality

const alpha = (foo) => {};
const beta = (foo, bar) => {};

function gamma (one, two) { return one };

const functionExpressionResult = c(alpha, beta);

console.log(functionExpressionResult.length === 1); // assert using known arity
console.log(functionExpressionResult === alpha); // assert with standard equality
```

Comment: Even function expressions can be named. Try `functionExpressionResult.name == "alpha"`

Comment: Node v4.0.0 seems to be giving me an empty string.

Comment: [You'll need an update](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-function_name_property_variables_(function)) :-)